# Tablet forgets default launcher

Tags: launcher, asus-eee-pad-transformer, default-applications

I updated the firmware on my Transformer Infinity a couple weeks back. I had been using the Nova Launcher on it and ever since the update the tablet asks me which launcher I'd like to use every time I restart it. I choose the Nova launcher and choose "Always", but the next time I restart it does it again.

Is there any way to fix that?

**Update**:

The tablet is now forgetting the launcher quite frequently, even when I haven't rebooted. Simply hitting the "Home" button while in an app will often bring up the message asking which launcher I'd like to use.

I also believe that I have determined that it is *not* a problem with the Nova Launcher. I tried installing a different launcher and using it, but I have the same problem. I also have the same problem with the stock launcher. It seems that simply having multiple launchers installed is causing me problems. Any help resolving this issue would, of course, be much appreciated. It's becoming very frustrating.

Comment: I don't have a Transformer, but I face a similar issue back when I was using the Nexus One. Is it possible that you have installed Nova on the sd card? Go to Settings -> Apps, Look for Nova Launcher and make sure it is installed on the internal memory.

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh I don't even have an SD Card, just internal memory.

Comment: Can you check nonetheless? Some tablets and phones have __two__ types of internal memory (one of them is called an Internal SD Card), I've came across a couple of phones like that. The [Internal Storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info) tag has more info abut this.

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh I don't see anything on that screen that indicates where it's installed. What exactly am I looking for?

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh – I believe the Samsung Galaxy Nexus (i515) has them as one and the same...