# How can I check whether an app is installed on internal storage or the internal SD?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, internal-sd

I asked another [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55950/tablet-forgets-default-launcher) about problems with the default launcher and one user suggested that I might need to check that my app is installed on the internal storage or the internal SD card, but I can't find anywhere in the app settings that shows that. How can I check where the app is installed?